# Any usage for Solar beyond 4 x 3 (max) skill upgrades?

Tags: awesomenauts

Just about at least 1 in 10 of my (lowish ranked) Awesomenauts matches becomes a rather long game, where I easily reach the point where I've upgraded all 4 skills three times. Like this Swoop game:

[image: 4 x 3 upgrades for Swoop]

In the screenshot my money was 504, but at the end of this game it was 1200+. **Is there any way at all to utilize Solar after you've already bought 4 x 3 upgrades?**

The [Solar entry on the Awesomenauts Wikia](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Solar) holds no relevant info, nor does any of the pages in the [Solar category](http://awesomenauts.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Solar). I've tried searching in the UI if there's anything I could do with the money but no dice. However, coming from [dota-2](/questions/tagged/dota-2) (where it rarely happens that you have *no* way to spend gold anymore), I feel like I'm missing something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not, no. Once all skills are upgraded, there is no way to spend Solar. You can continue collecting it for achievement requirements, but it won't help your in game character.

This is the case in many MOBA-style games. Coming from League of Legends (and playing Awesomenauts a lot as well), there is always a point where you can't spend any gold. In League, it usually comes around the 35-50 minute mark (or later), depending on how well you farm etc. In Awesomenauts, it depends on your character, but is generally a LOT shorter.

Remember, Awesomenauts is not meant as an hour-long game: rather, 30 minute or less (even 10 minute) games seem to be the norm. If you find yourself running out of things to spend Solar on quickly, celebrate! You're at max build. Dominate the enemies, and play another round.